# Assign value to a bitvector (SMTLIB2, Z3)?

Tags: z3

I am using Z3 version 3.0. I want to assign a value to a bitvector variable, like below. 
But Z3 reports error "invalid function application, sort mismatch on argument at position 2 in line 3".

It seems wrong with my constant #x0a? how can i fix this?

Thanks

```
(set-logic QF_BV)
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (= a #x0a))
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the SMT-LIB 2.0 standard, `#x0a` is a bitvector of size 8. You get the sort mismatch error because the constant `a` is a bitvector of size 32.
You can avoid the type/sort error message by rewriting your example as:

```
(set-logic QF_BV)
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (= a #x0000000a))
(check-sat)
```

SMT-LIB also supports bitvector literals of the form `(_ bv[num] [size])`, where `[num]` is in decimal notation, and `[size]` is the size of the bitvector.
Thus, you can also write the bitvector literal `#x0000000a` as `(_ bv10 32)`.

BTW, SMT-LIB also supports bitvector literals in binary notation. For example, `#b010` is a bitvector of size 3.